# Для чего при наследовании из RecyclerView.Adapter добавляется вложенный класс в угловых скобках?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics

Код из урока по Android Studio, но я хочу понять, что значит этот синтаксис в Kotlin `<PlantAdapter.PlantHolder>`  - и для чего он используется
В комментах , что я понял.

```
class PlantAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter <PlantAdapter.PlantHolder> () {

    // PlantAdapter наследуется от вложенного класса RecyclerView.Adapter
    // Дальше в угловых скобках вложенный класс <PlantAdapter.PlantHolder> - который есть ниже

    class PlantHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder (item) {
    }
}
```

Я создал модель - этих классов и чтобы я не вводил в <> результат не менялся. Как будто там может быть любой тип данных. Хотя в уроке указывали , что нужно чтобы , именно, это было прописано <PlantAdapter.PlantHolder>

Ниже модель которую я сделал

```
// begin of hidden part
open class RecyclerView<T>() {
    fun printRecyclerView () {
        println("RecyclerView Parent print")
    }
}
// end of hidden part
class PlantAdapter (varPlantAdapter: Int): RecyclerView <PlantAdapter.PlantHolder2> () {

    class PlantHolder (int: Int, str : String) {
        val int = int
        fun printPlantHolder () {
            println("PlantHolder Inner child - $int")
        }
    }

    class PlantHolder2 (int: Int) {
        val int = int
        fun printPlantHolder2 () {
            println("PlantHolder2 Inner child - $int")
        }
    }
    // я этот класс создал, чтобы проверить поменяется ли что-то если указать его в <>
    // ничего не поменялось, ему ввобще все равно
}

class ExampleMainTwo () {
    fun exe () {
        val obj = PlantAdapter (0)
        obj.printRecyclerView() // RecyclerView Parent print

        val obj2 = PlantAdapter.PlantHolder (1, "Hello")
        obj2.printPlantHolder() // PlantHolder Inner child - 1
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Тип, указанный в объявлении адаптера - это тип холдера. Он придёт в метод onBindViewHolder. Если тип не указать свой - будет базовый и придётся явно кастовать к нужному. Примеры у вас некорректные - т.к. не учитывается использование дженерика в методах класса

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

В объявлении библиотечного адаптера указано не `<T>` как у вас, а
`<VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder?>` - это значит, что типизировать свой наследник адаптера вы можете только наследником `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, что не позволит вам даже пытаться использовать в качестве холдера неправильный тип. А конкретизация дженерика при наследовании - не позволит использовать даже другие наследники `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Всё это даёт типо-безопасность уже на этапе компиляции плюс синтаксический сахар - вам не нужно проверять тип и приводить к конкретному, все параметры и возврашаемые типы конкретизируются и проверяются компилятором.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться